# How to use MUI in Redwood JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redwoodjs

I want to install MUI in the Redwood JS. But when i ran the command in the project directory

```
yarn add @mui/material
```

An error popped up in the console saying

```
error Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than 
the workspace itself, which might not be what you want - if you really meant it, make 
it explicit by running this command again with the -W flag (or --ignore-workspace- 
root-check).
```

I have been searching across the docs, but couldn't find anything.

[image]

I checked the [commands in Redwiid JS](https://redwoodjs.com/docs/webpack-configuration.html#tailwind-css), rw setup ui  is the command for adding ui libraries. However, only Tailwind & Chakra is mentioned there. Is there a way to add MUI as UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redwood projects are usually created as monorepos. From their [website](https://redwoodjs.com/) under the section:

`How it's Organized`

> Redwood places both the frontend and backend code in a single **monorepo**.

The problem is that you are likely running `yarn add @mui/material` from the root of the project, rather than inside the frontend (`/web`) project.

Comment: thanks, package is installed and working. Is there a drawback to this approach?

Comment: @Rusty to what approach? The monorepo? Monorepo approach is quite common when starting new projects, especially with javascript projects. There is really no downside if you know how to manage dependencies and other concerns in an effective way. One of the ways redwood manages the dependencies is by making use of [yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/)

Comment: i meant using yarn directly in web directory instead of using redwood setup command.

Comment: @Rusty I don't think that should be a problem, unless redwood has it's own dependency management. I'm not really familiar with it, but I see nothing in the [cli commands](https://redwoodjs.com/docs/cli-commands) which can be used to install dependencies. However, I do see in one of their [tutorials](https://learn.redwoodjs.com/docs/tutorial2/prerequisites#using-the-example-repo) that they use `yarn install`

Answer (score 1):

At the top level we have three directories, api, scripts and web. Redwood separates the backend (api) and frontend (web) concerns into their own paths in the codebase. (Yarn refers to these as "workspaces". In Redwood, we refer to them as "sides.") When you add packages going forward you'll need to specify which workspace they should go in. For example (don't run these commands, we're just looking at the syntax):

```js
yarn workspace web add marked
yarn workspace api add better-fs
```

in this case you only need Mui on the front:

```js
yarn workspace web add @mui/material
```